# Targeting :disabled field in Safari with CSS

Tags: html, css, ipad, input, safari

I'm working on a website that will be viewed across three browsers - Chrome, FireFox, and Safari (both desktop and iPad).

I am trying to change the color of a disabled field on all browsers, so I have been using the following code:

```css
input:disabled {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<input value="testing" disabled></input>
```

I want the color of the disabled text to show as black. This works perfectly in Chrome and FireFox, but in Safari, it's still showing up as gray. Can anyone give any suggestions on how to change this field in Safari?

Answer (score 2):

Solved this by adding the following to my CSS:

```
-webkit-text-fill-color: black;
```

Hope this helps someone else one day!